# How to get the process that is running

Tags: linux, process, cpu, ps

How do I get the process that is running currently on a Linux system? When I do a `ps -aux`, it returns me a list of several processes that are running on the machine.

But a processor can only run one process at a time, right? So how come so many processes run at the same time on the processor? Even if the context switch happens so fast, How can I get that just one process that is running at a given time on the CPU?

Comment: in ps aux output , there is a column specifying STAT , in you listing there must be a process with R STAT, this is that process running on CPU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ps aux` output , there is a column specifying STAT , in you listing there must be a process with `R` STAT, this is that process running on CPU

Comment: One of which invariably is `ps` itself. Or the only one, if you have a uniprocessor system.

Comment: right, in uniprocessor system, whichever tool we used will become active process and will list itself as running, or am I missing something??

Comment: Exactly. So it's not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you have **top** command which supports focusing on a single process to monitor cpu and memory

```
top -pid PID
```